# Ionic local storage remove item

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Can someone help me to create a method to remove from ionic local storage?

So far I have tried

```
    set: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = value;
    },
    get: function(key) {
      return $window.localStorage[key];
    },
    setObject: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function(key) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key]);
    },
    removeItem: function(key){
      $window.localstorage.splice(key, 1);
    }
```

removeItem doesnt work at all. I want to remove by positions, not by key.

Comment: Just use `$window.localStorage.removeItem(key)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `localStorage` as an array, while it isn't. It has default functions to remove an item:

```
removeItem: function(key){
    $window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
}
```

If you want to remove by index, you have to get the item first:

```
removeByIndex: function (index) {
    $window.localStorage.removeItem($window.localStorage.key(index));
}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried your solution. When I add each object to my array I create a unique name like task0, task1 and more. Then I try to removeItem(task0) or removeItem(task1). it gets removes but I get an error when refreshing the app that says Unexpected token u.

Comment: Maybe the question really is, how do I remove a JSON object no a single value.

Comment: Do you mean you want to delete part of data in localStorage that is stored in a single key?

Comment: I am trying to delete a whole entry.

Answer (score 0):

Try the built in methods, which will help to complete the whole transaction of the removal of your `key:value` from `LocalStorage`

https://auth0.com/docs/native-platforms/ionic#8

Answer (score 0):

This would be the best way. With this factory you can create, retrieve, or delete any created key

```
.factory('sessionService',['$http',function($http){
  return {
     set:function(key,value){
     return localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(value));
   },
   get:function(key){
     return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
   },
   destroy:function(key){
     return localStorage.removeItem(key);
   },
 };
}])
```